# Can the MacBook Pro 14” charge via its USB C port?

Tags: usb, thunderbolt, charging

I see that the new (2022) MacBook Pro 14” has gone back to a separate charging port for a dedicated charger to hook up to.
Can it also be charged via its USB C ports as well?

I’m used to doing this on my 2019 MacBook Pro 16”, for example taking power from the USB Thunderbolt connection with my Apple-bought LG 27” 5k screen.

Can the 14” be charged via its USB port?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can charge a 14" M1 MBP with a USB-C cable.

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT212755

Comment: nice short quick answer.